# Django rest framework: how to make a view to delete multiple objects?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am building a simple Photos-Albums app with Django Rest Framework (DRF). I would like to be able to delete multiple albums at once by supplying an array of ids. I am using `viewsets.ModelViewSet` for the basic views.

```
class AlbumViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Album.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AlbumSerializer
```

I have managed to create a view to show the albums before the delete operation by adding this function to my `views.py` file.

```
@api_view(['GET', 'DELETE'])
def delete_albums(request):
    """
        GET:    list all albums
        DELETE: delete multiple albums
    """

    if request.method == 'GET':
        albums = Album.objects.all()
        serializer = AlbumSerializer(albums, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        ids = request.data
        albums = Album.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
        for album in albums:
            album.delete()
        serializer = AlbumSerializer(albums, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

If I run `curl -X delete -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8000/albums/delete -d '{"data":[1,2,3]}'`  then it will delete albums with ids 1,2,3.

This is OK, except that:

- It's not class-based, and I'd prefer to have everything class-based if possible
- I would prefer to have a form in the view that lets me input an array e.g. [1,2,3], hit a delete button, and then see the results of the query in the browser, much like when one posts a new object through the interface.

Can anyone please outline how to achieve that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@action` decorator

```py
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.request import Request

#import your model and serializer classes

class AlbumViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Album.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AlbumSerializer

    @action(methods=["DELETE"], detail=False)
    def delete(self, request: Request):
        delete_id = request.data
        delete_albums = self.queryset.filter(id__in=delete_id)
        
        delete_albums.delete()
        return Response(self.serializer_class(delete_albums,many=True).data)
```

assuming your `ModelViewSet` API point was `/api/albums`
you could now make a delete request to `/api/albums/delete`

You could check out the full document on viewsets at [`ViewSet`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/)
and on how to use [`action`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset-actions) decorator provided by the DjangoRESTFramework

Comment: Make sure to check that the user has permission to perform such operation by passing a named parameter `permission_class` as a List of Permission classes to the @action decorator . For example ```@action(methods=['DELETE'], details=False, permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated, isAdminUser]) ... ```

Comment: queryset has a method `.delete()` for that. So `delete_albums.delete()` is enough.

Comment: Yes [@J.T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18067531/j-t) that right,  there will be no need to loop over the albums

Comment: It's `detail=False` not `details=False` in the decorator