# How to make a Delete endpoint for a list of objects with a given condition in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework, python-requests

Given an REST API developed with Django Rest Framework, what would be the proper solution for creating an endpoint that deletes multiple objects , based on a criteria that is send along with the Delete request?

I have a simple model for products. One of the model-fields is the brand. Now I would like to let another python script send a delete request to the API and remove all products that are from brand X.

The answer from this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71001947/django-rest-framework-how-to-make-a-view-to-delete-multiple-objects) is exactly what I want. However, this it seems that the current version of the python [request package](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/) does not allow a data-body to be sent along with a delete request.

I currently solved it my changing the endpoint in a POST request and overriding the functions as shown below:

```
class DeleteProductList(APIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = productserializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        brand_to_delete = request.data.get('brand_to_delete')
        delete_products = self.queryset.filter(brand=brand_to_delete)
        delete_products.delete()
        return Response( self.serializer_class(delete_products,many=True).data)
```

Now any python script can send a Post request to this endpoint to delete the products with brand X:

```
requests.post(url=delete_url, headers=headers, data={"brand_to_delete":'X'})
```

This works fine, but it seems not the best practise: A POST request for a deletion is used. In addition, the urls.py will look ugly and not intuitive. The modelviewset (ProductViewSet) is nicely handled by the router, but an additional endpoint is needed for deleting the objects.

```
from products.api import views as bv

router = DefaultRouter()

router.register(r"products", bv.ProductdViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path("", include(router.urls)),
    path("delete-products/", bv.DeleteProductList.as_view())
]
```

What would be the best practise for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in this [post](https://reqbin.com/req/ke7ui8ri/http-delete-body) you can solve the problem passing data via query parameters and changing your code like this:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.request import Request


# import your model and serializer classes

class AlbumViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Album.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AlbumSerializer

    @action(methods=["DELETE"], details=False, )
    def delete(self, request: Request):
        brand = request.GET["brand_to_delete"]
        album_qs = Album.objects.filter(brand=brand_to_delete)
        album_qs.delete()
        return Response(self.serializer_class(album_qs, many=True).data)
```

and the call:

```
requests.delete(url=f"{delete_url}?brand_to_delete=X", headers=headers)
```